# how to set top and bottom margin in addHTML

Tags: javascript

how to add margin-bottom and top at multiple pages pdf?

I added plugins jspdf and html2canvas.

```
               var pdf = new jsPDF( 'p', 'mm', [400, 455]);       
               var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#exportthis': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                    }
                };

                margins = {
                    bottom:10,
                    top:10,
                    left:10,
                    right:10
               };


            pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('exportthis'), 5, 10, {pagesplit: true },
                   function(dispose){
                    var pageCount = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages(); 
                    for(i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) { 
                    pdf.setPage(i); 
                    pdf.text(195,450, pdf.internal.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber + "/" + pageCount +"\n");   
                 }
               pdf.save("Report.pdf");
            },margins);
```

output

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012181/jspdf-add-margins-to-pdf-page

Comment: I try this but same error and tx for response@Er_sherlockian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPDF allows margin and useFor Feature. You can set the margin properties like below:

```
const pdf = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'a4'); // For A4 Sheet layout
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('print-section'), 25, 50, {
    retina: true,
    pagesplit: true,
    margin: {
      top: 50,
      right: 25,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 25,
      useFor: 'page' // This property is mandatory to keep the margin to supsequent pages
    }
  }, function() {
    pdf.save('test.pdf');
  });
```

See the output below:

[image]

Comment: I am trying html to pdf using pdf.addImage(). Will you please help?
Have tried below code. but NO LUCK :(

pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height, {
                    retina: true,
                    pagesplit: true,
                    margin: {
                        top: 50,
                        right: 25,
                        bottom: 50,
                        left: 25,
                        useFor: 'page' 
                    }
                });

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('exportthis'), 5, 10, {
        pagesplit: true,
        margin: margins
    },
    function(dispose) {
        var pageCount = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
        for (i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
            pdf.setPage(i);
            pdf.text(195, 450, pdf.internal.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber + "/" + pageCount + "\n");
        }
        pdf.save("Report.pdf");
    });
```

Comment: @ Er_sherlockian thanks for the response but its same error display

Comment: I'll have a look into the documentation again.

Comment: @Rushidave ok. Can you tell me which version of jspdf you are using?

Comment: I m used jspdf 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using changes of the addhtml.js file
**https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/1450/files** and its work for me