# How can I add margins to a jsPDF document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I creating a document through jsPDF without using the function "doc.fromHTML". I can define left margin for every text but I cannot do it for margin right so when the text is too large it take more width than the page. This is a snippet of my code. So basically I want to add margins for every page.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

doc.text("2. OBSERVACIONES", 40, 500);

doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.setFontType('normal');

doc.text("{Análisis otras especies en número en XXX: Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°, Nombre+N°} {Observaciones otras especies en número}", 40, 520);

doc.save('newPDF');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsPdf add margins to pdf page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012181/jspdf-add-margins-to-pdf-page)

Comment: @MiguelBarra Did you get any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here -> http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/examples/basic.html

```
 var doc = new jsPDF('p','mm','letter')
       , size = [14]
       , font = ""
       , font, size, lines
       , verticalOffset = 40 // inches on a 8.5 x 11 inch sheet,

texty =   "put your text here!!",

lines = doc.setFont(font[0], font[0])
                       .setFontSize(size)
                       .splitTextToSize(texty, 166), //this is how long you want your text

           doc.text(25,  verticalOffset + size / 72, lines),

           verticalOffset += (lines.length + 25) * size / 72;


    //you can combine this method with doc.text
       doc.setFont("helvetica");
           doc.setFontType("regular");
           doc.setFontSize(22);
           doc.text(40,40, `Combine here!`); 

    doc.save('Test.pdf');
```