# jsPdf: set margin using html() plugin

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf

I am using the jsPDF to convert HTML into PDF file. It works fine but I want to add margin around the page so that text should not get cut when content splits into pages. But I didn't find any way to add margin to the PDF file. I am using following code to add the text. Note that I am using the new `.html()` plugin, not `.addHtml()`, which is [deprecated](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML), as indicated by their documentation. So this is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012181/jspdf-add-margins-to-pdf-page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="jsPDF-master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
       <label><span>Standard</span></label>
       <label><span>Planning item number:</span></label>
    </div>                    
    <button onclick="exportPDF()" style="float:right;">Download</button>
    <script>
        function exportPDF () {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
            var margins = {
                top: 40, bottom: 60, left: 40, right: 200
            };
            pdf.html(document.getElementById("content"), {
                callback : function (pdf) {
                    pdf.save("a4.pdf");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to add margin to the PDF pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsPdf add margins to pdf page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012181/jspdf-add-margins-to-pdf-page)

Comment: i have used jsPdf, and i think that the best way to accomplish your need is to edit the margin of your html and use jsPdf just for generating the pdf.

Comment: @Kaddath, that example contains the `addHTML` function, but here my example contains `html` function only.

Comment: @Hsaidooo, that can manage the top, left and right margin. but bottom margin cannot be handled.

Comment: You are not using the margins object in your code. But I know that's not the reason it won't work anyway.

Comment: @SuhasBhattu Did you get any solution so far ?

Comment: It is a (open) bug: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2924

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this option in the method

```
autoPaging: 'text'
```

Your code will look like this

```js
pdf.html(document.getElementById("content"), {
  callback: function (pdf) {
    pdf.save("a4.pdf");
  },
  autoPaging: 'text'
});
```

Text won't get cut when content splits into pages

Answer (score 0):

Margin would be passed in as part of the options object, which is the second argument to your `pdf.html(element, options)` call.

The acceptable values of the margin property are: number, array of 2 or array of 4:
`margin: 40`
OR
`margin: [40,60]`
OR
`margin: [40,200,60,40]`

See Worker.prototype.setMargin on line 499 of the jsPDF html plugin:
https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/modules_html.js.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="jsPDF-master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
       <label><span>Standard</span></label>
       <label><span>Planning item number:</span></label>
    </div>                    
    <button onclick="exportPDF()" style="float:right;">Download</button>
    <script>
        function exportPDF () {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
            pdf.html(document.getElementById("content"), {
                callback : function (pdf) {
                    pdf.save("a4.pdf");
                },
                margin: [40, 200, 60, 40]
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```