# jsPDF- html() new function has no feature to set margin to pdf page

Tags: jspdf

i am using jsPDF into vue cli application, but i am unable to find any solution to set the margins to the pdf page. all the text and images are getting overflowed on the pages.
i want to set all the four margins. the syntax to set margins given in the jsPDF documentation is also not working.

this is my function to generate and download pdf:

```
downloadpdf() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
  pdf.setFontSize("10");
  pdf.setLineWidth("100");
  pdf.setTextColor("darkblue");

  // Printing text
  var vuejsinformation = `JQuery is a lightweight, "write less, do more", JavaScript library.`;
  pdf.text(vuejsinformation, 10, 10);
  //pdf.save("Sample.pdf");

  // Printing a complete div container who has class pdfrapper
  pdf.html(window.jQuery(".pdfwrapper").get(0), {
    callback: function (pdf) {
      pdf.save("Sample.pdf");
    },
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
  });
},
```

how to set all the four margins ?

Comment: You have an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012181/jspdf-add-margins-to-pdf-page

Comment: Hi, as per the latest version of the jsPDF, fromHtml() is deprecated. so this answer is not helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an option var in the jspdf.html() method like this:

```js
jspdf.html(src, {
margin: number,
html2canvas: {width: number, height: number, ...}
...
})
```

However there seems to be an issue where the margin is ignored when using this method see https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2924.
It will probably be fixed soon :).

Here's the documentation for the jspdf.html() method http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html

Answer (score -1):

This example for jsPDF version 2.1.1 should give you an idea on how to setup the margins.

```
var pageWidth = 8.5,
  lineHeight = 1.2,
  margin = 0.5,
  maxLineWidth = pageWidth - margin * 2,
  fontSize = 24,
  ptsPerInch = 72,
  oneLineHeight = (fontSize * lineHeight) / ptsPerInch,
  text =
    "Two households, both alike in dignity,\n" +
    "In fair Verona, where we lay our scene,\n" +
    "From ancient grudge break to new mutiny,\n" +
    "Where civil blood makes civil hands unclean.\n" +
    "From forth the fatal loins of these two foes\n" +
    "A pair of star-cross'd lovers take their life;\n" +
    "Whole misadventured piteous overthrows\n" +
    "Do with their death bury their parents' strife.\n" +
    "The fearful passage of their death-mark'd love,\n" +
    "And the continuance of their parents' rage,\n" +
    // Notice that the following will be wrapped to two lines automatically!
    "Which, but their children's end, nought could remove, Is now the two hours' traffic of our stage;\n" +
    "The which if you with patient ears attend,\n" +
    "What here shall miss, our toil shall strive to mend.",
  doc = new jsPDF({
    unit: "in",
    lineHeight: lineHeight
  }).setProperties({ title: "String Splitting" });

// splitTextToSize takes your string and turns it in to an array of strings,
// each of which can be displayed within the specified maxLineWidth.
var textLines = doc
  .setFont("helvetica")
  .setFontSize(fontSize)
  .splitTextToSize(text, maxLineWidth);
 
// doc.text can now add those lines easily; otherwise, it would have run text off the screen!
doc.text(textLines, margin, margin + 2 * oneLineHeight);

// You can also calculate the height of the text very simply:
var textHeight = (textLines.length * fontSize * lineHeight) / ptsPerInch;
doc
  .setFont("Helvetica", "bold")
  .text(
    "Text Height: " + textHeight + " inches",
    margin,
    margin + oneLineHeight
  );
```